# Uploading files to user specific directories in firebase storage for android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am trying to upload a file using firebase storage in Android. But i am receiving the following exception:

```
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                    User does not have permission to access this object.
                     Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
E/StorageException: The server has terminated the upload session
                    java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzs(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzr(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zzl(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzx.run(Unknown Source)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                     Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"  }}
                        at bft.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):147)
                        at bft.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):119)
                        at bfn.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):5)
                        at nd.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):12)
                        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zza.transactAndReadExceptionReturnVoid(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zzm.zze(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zzq.zza(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zzf.zza(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzc(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source) 
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zzl(Unknown Source) 
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzx.run(Unknown Source) 
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                    User does not have permission to access this object.
                     Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
E/StorageException: The server has terminated the upload session
                    java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzs(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzr(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zzl(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzx.run(Unknown Source)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                     Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"  }}
                        at bft.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):147)
                        at bft.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):119)
                        at bfn.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):5)
                        at nd.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12874022@12.8.74 (040308-204998136):12)
                        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zza.transactAndReadExceptionReturnVoid(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zzm.zze(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zzq.zza(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zzf.zza(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzc(Unknown Source)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source) 
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zzl(Unknown Source) 
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzx.run(Unknown Source) 
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

My Java Code:

```java
File f= new File(filePath.getPath());
mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
StorageReference userReference = mStorageRef.child(mAuth.getUid());
StorageReference fileReference = userReference.child(f.getName());               
fileReference.putFile(filePath)
```

My security rule in Firebase:

```
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{userId} {      
            allow read,write: if request.auth.uid==userId;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fixed when I changed the security rule to :

```
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{userId} {
            match /{allPaths=**} {
                allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```