# error Caused by: java.io.IOException: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation" }}

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

> I was getting this error Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"  }} or user does not  have permission to access this object.  when i try to upload data in firebase
> firestore and i already grant the permission in the firestore rule.
>
> here is my code

```
package com.example.db1;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;


import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
    EditText Name, Email, Contact,Password;
    Button Register;
    ImageView user_image;
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    ProgressBar progressBar;


    String user_id;
    Uri download_uri;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    Bitmap compressed;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        Name = findViewById(R.id.name);
        Email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        Contact = findViewById(R.id.contact);
        Register = findViewById(R.id.register);
        Password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        user_image = findViewById(R.id.im1);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.pb1);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        user_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {


                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Register.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Register.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                    } else {
                        choseImage();
                    }
                } else {
                    choseImage();
                }


            }
        });

        Register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final String name = Name.getText().toString().trim();
                final String email = Email.getText().toString().trim();
                final String contact = Contact.getText().toString().trim();
                final String pass = Password.getText().toString().trim();



                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(contact) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass) && user_image!=null){

                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


                    compressed.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);


                    byte[] thumbData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();


                    UploadTask image_path = storageReference.child("user_image").child(user_id + ".jpg").putBytes(thumbData);


                    image_path.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {


                        @Override


                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                storeData(task, name, email, contact, pass);
                            } else {
                                String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "(IMAGE Error) : " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }

                    });
                }
                else{
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Please fill all fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void storeData(Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task, String name, String email, String contact, String pass) {

        if (task != null) {
            download_uri = task.getResult().getUploadSessionUri();

            Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
            user.put("mName", name);
            user.put("mEmail", email);
            user.put("mContact", contact);
            user.put("mPassword", pass);
            user.put("userImage",download_uri.toString());

            db.collection("users").add(user).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this,"User data save successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(Register.this,Result.class));
                }
            })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e);
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this,"User data is not Save",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Error in Data Upload",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void choseImage() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"pick an image"),1);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode== RESULT_OK) {

            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                compressed = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                user_image.setImageBitmap(compressed);
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52043560/uploading-files-to-user-specific-directories-in-firebase-storage-for-android) out.

Answer (score 1):

It is well worth to take a look into your [Firestore rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#basic_readwrite_rules):

> Basic rules consist of a match statement specifying a document path and an allow expression detailing when reading the specified data is allowed:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Match any document in the 'cities' collection
    match /cities/{city} {
      allow read: if <condition>;
      allow write: if <condition>;
    }
  }
}
```

Your error points to this **Note**:

> You can only access documents that your security rules specifically allow you to access.

For instance: in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52043560/uploading-files-to-user-specific-directories-in-firebase-storage-for-android) mentioned by @Alex Mamo, the solution was:

```
service firebase.storage {
 match /b/{bucket}/o {
  match /{userId} {
    match /{allPaths=**}{
     allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
   } 
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for kotlin,
go rules on firebase storage and change with place that marked with quotes
... allow read, write: `"if request.auth!=null;"`